# Is there any chance Workbench has a case sensitive setting for Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have been using MySql workbench for an online database I was able to set everything up but to my suprise and my boss' amazement, Workbench was actually case sensitive. We wrote two select statement, one worked and the other didn't work because of the case sensitivity. 
Tried again, and it seems to be the case:

I am running: - `MySql Workbench 5.2` on `Windows XP`.

Any reason for this?

Comment: Are you sure the table columns haven't been declared with a [case sensitive or binary collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html)?

Comment: i didnt create the database myself so I can't assume that. is there a way to check?

Comment: There has to be a way to see the table's definition, you just need to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This has been part of the underlying functionality of mysql for a while. at least in all versions of 5.x

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names. This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

Same quote exists in [the PDF 5.0 reference manual page 806](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-5.0-en.a4.pdf#page=806) 
as well as [the WEB 5.7 reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Additionally, if you want to *change* this functionality so that identifiers are not case sensitive, there is instructions to do so in manuals.

[Another answer on stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59407/how-to-make-mysql-table-name-case-insensitive-in-ubuntu) explains in simple English the needed change.

Edit the [mysqld] section of the `my.cnf` file. `my.cnf` can be found:

under a LAMPP/XAMPP installation ... :

```
/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

stand alone mysql server :

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

in that section Add the Line

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
```